# Wix MSI do create a path a I need, but code works in debug

Tags: c#, wix, .net-framework-version

Good Morning!
Well, I want to build an MSI with Wix.

I have a class like this:

```
    public static class Settings
    {
        static SettingsFields GetSettings()
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("./Settings/settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            return new SettingsFields
            {
                updatesCheckingTimer = (int)long.Parse(configuration["Settings:updatesCheckingTimer"]),
                rootPath = configuration["Settings:rootPath"],
            };
        }

        static SettingsFields configuration = GetSettings();
        
        private static int updatesCheckingTimer = configuration.updatesCheckingTimer;
        public static int UpdatesCheckingTimer
        {
            get { return updatesCheckingTimer; }
            set { updatesCheckingTimer = value; }
        }

        private static string rootPath = configuration.rootPath;
        public static string RootPath
        {
           get { return rootPath; }
           set { rootPath = value; } 
        }
    }
```

This work on debug, I mean, the program generates the path "rootPath" (i.e. "C:/example") and install and run the service.
But when I build a MSI, the service is installed but not run, and the path is not created.

I guess is a problem with the wxs file, but I can't find it.

I have tried to create on the installation path another path called Settings and put it inside the file settings(in order to keep the path in the configurationBuilder) and try to add to the msi the couples of dlls needed for the configurationBuilder, but I can't make the MSI works...

**UPDATE:**

Seeing the event log, I get this error:

```
Application: UpdatesManagerService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder, Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at Installer.UpdatesManager.Settings.Settings.GetSettings()
   at Installer.UpdatesManager.Settings.Settings..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at Installer.UpdatesManager.Settings.Settings.get_InstallationFilesPath()
   at Installer.UpdatesManager.Controllers.UpdatesChecker..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at Installer.UpdatesManager.Controllers.UpdatesChecker+<Run>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

So, the problem is Wix can't find the route "./Settings/settings.json"

Comment: Any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Is the settings class you have above, part of UpdatesManagerService.exe? Is UpdatesManagerService.exe what you are trying to install via WiX?

Comment: hoy I can chek if the settings class is part of UpdatesManagerService.exe? and Yes. i guess I am trying to install the exe... (the code is not mine, I just trying improve this part)
thanks @cskwrd